# Block element modification with use of clip-path attribute?

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path

I am trying to create custom shaped div with use of clip-path:

```css
#chevron {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("http://imgur.com/2IZCVpi.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 40%, 50% 52%, 0 38%, 0 0, 50% 8%);
}
```

```html
<div id="chevron"></div>
```

Everything is fine in Chrome but IE and Firefox don't support clip-path. I tried also SVG but support is also not good. Maybe I can solve it with two images (in shape of arrows and color of main background) before and after div element? How would you solve it?

Comment: I'd rather clip the image in photoshop and use it, if I had to use only the part that you're showing right now.

Comment: There will be an administration and user will be able to upload custom image to this chevron. So some modification in PS or other editor is not good.